# Average rating in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to print post with the highest ratings.
The problem i have ran in to is that the the ratings is stored in an array `["rc_rating"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(1) "4" }` and my WP_Query is just picking the first rating and i just cant wrap my head around how to get the avrage from the array (total beginner in PHP)

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => 'recept',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'meta_key'      => 'rc_rating',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
)); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 

       get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

    endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you post your full query with the loop itself ?

Comment: @amarinediary Added the loop to the question :)

Comment: Can you post template-parts/content too. So I can understand a bit better what you want to display

Comment: The template-part i just an div with the thumbnail and title. 

The loop its self displaying the posts but its not in the right order due to it only picking upp the first string in the array so there could be an post with avrage rating 3 first in the loop just because the first rating was a 5 (1 to 5 rating)